# 2d top down smooth pathfinding libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

I'm trying to make a buddy ai that follows the player (being controlled by you) around and at the moment it works but when I add collision detection it doesn't work very well when the buddy hits an obstacle. I was just wondering what would be the best approach (like perhaps an implementation of the a* algorithm) to making the ai movement smooth and so it avoids obstacles?
Here is the update method currently for my buddy class:

```
public void update() {

    setBounds(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());

    float xDiff = Math.abs(player.getX() - getX());
    float yDiff = Math.abs(player.getY() - getY());

    if (player.getX() > getX() && xDiff > buddyDistance) {
        setX(getX()+speed);
    }
    else if (player.getX() < getX() && xDiff > buddyDistance) {
        setX(getX()-speed);
    }

    if (player.getY() > getY() && yDiff > buddyDistance) {
        setY(getY()+speed);
    }
    else if (player.getY() < getY() && yDiff > buddyDistance) {
        setY(getY()-speed);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is movement restricted to a graph, say a grid? If it is, I do have a possible solution right away. But if the player moves in any direction with arbitrary step-size and you do want the buddy to follow suit without constraining it to move along some graph, then I will have to think further.

Comment: no the player is not restricted to a grid, im not using a tiled map or anything like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution that is easy to implement and might work depending on your type of obstacles is the use of potential fields.

The idea is simple: The player behaves like a magnet that pulls the buddy towards him. At the same time, obstacles repel the buddy so that the buddy avoids them.

I am going to use vectors to explain it first, instead of Java, for better readability.

Let's say, `b` is the buddy's position and `p` the player's and `o_1, ... o_k` are the positions of your obstacles.

Each of `b, p, o_1, ..., o_k` are 2 dimensional vectors with `x` and `y` coordinates.

Then the vector `(p-b)` is the vector that points from the buddy to the player.   What we also need is the vector `(b-o_i)` which points from obstacle `i` to the buddy. Additionally, instead of using the vectors `(p-b)`, `(b-o_i)` directly, we first normalize them.

Then, `normalized(p-b)` is already all we need to pull the buddy to the player.

For repelling the buddy from obstacles, we would like the repulsion to be strong if the buddy is close to it and small (or even zero) if the buddy is far away from it. Therefore, an obvious choice would be to scale the direction that we want, i.e. `normalized(b-o_i)`, with `1/|b-o_i|`, where |.| denotes the norm of a vector.

Now, we can simply mix all these "magnetic forces" with:

```
w = normalized(p-b) + normalized(b-o_1)/|b-o_1| + ... + normalized(b-o_l)/|b-o_k|
```

This vector `w` generally points towards the player but whenever the buddy is close to obstacles it will be repelled from them, which is exactly what you want.

But how can we make sure that the buddy moves at the right speed?
This is easy. We normalize `w` and then scale by speed. That is, our final velocity vector is `v = speed*w/|w|`

This can easily be added into your code:

```
public void update() {

    setBounds(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight()); //I kept this from your code, but I don't actually know what it does

    float dx = player.getX() - getX(); //note: I removed abs
    float dy = player.getY() - getY();

    float norm = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

    //normalization:
    float wx = dx/norm;
    float wy = dy/norm;

    for (obstacle o : obstacles) { //assuming obstacles is an iterable datastructure containing instances of the class obstacle
         //note, it suffices to iterate over close by obstacles
         dx = getX() - o.getX();
         dy = getY() - o.getY();

         norm = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

         //normalization:
         float ox = dx/norm;
         float oy = dy/norm;

         //add scaling to get the repulsion force we want
         wx += ox/norm;
         wy += oy/norm;
    } 

    float norm_of_w = Math.sqrt(wx*wx + wy*wy);
    float vx = speed * wx / norm_of_w;
    float vy = speed * wy / norm_of_w;

    setX(getX() + vx);
    setY(getY() + vy);
}
```

Unfortunately, there are several things to consider:

- Different kinds of repulsion might work better than 1/|b-o_i|, for example 1/|b-o_i|^2.
- It might help to play around with the forces, for example try `c*(b-o_i)/|b-o_i|` for different values of `c` (i.e. `ox = c*dx/norm;` and so on). If `c` is too small, then the buddy will move into obstacles to some degree, if `c` is very large he will avoid them already when far away from them. Using different values of c for different obstacle sizes might also give a better result.
- The avoidance of obstacles works best if obstacles are circular shapes and there is enough room between two obstacles. Otherwise, the buddy might be stuck in local optima and the player will have to "rescue" him by moving to a location that pulls the buddy away from the local optimum.
- If obstacles are not nice and circular but large polygons, you can try a very large repulsion force that covers most of the polygon (i.e. a very large c for this kind of obstacle). The advantage is that the buddy can avoid the obstacle but unfortunately, if you want it to move closer to it, it will simply refuse due to the strong repulsion.
- It is important to keep in mind that `1/|b-o_i|` is large if buddy and obstacle are close. If they are at the same position, then your program will try to divide by zero. You might want to check for this case and avoid it.

---

That's it, but it might be worth noting that usually with potential fields, the idea is to use negative charge for the goal and positive charge for obstacles, i.e.

```
w = -|p-b| + 1/|b-o_1| + ... + 1/|b-o_k|
```

Note that here, w is only a scalar an not a vector. Then, gradient descent is applied to move towards the goal. This means the gradient of w with respect to b.x, b.y is computed. This gradient then points towards the direction to reach the player while avoiding obstacles. This is a better approach than what I proposed to you, but requires more math knowledge. Feel free to try or ask if this is what you want.

---

Most-likely, the best answer if obstacles have arbitrary shape and local minima are not acceptable for you is to use a Delaunay Triangulation combined with the Funnel Algorithm. You can read more about is in https://www.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/2006/AAAI06-148.pdf

But I assume you prefer something that is easy to implement.